# Capture "Go to today" click event on DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

How do I capture click event when user click the "Go to today" button on DateTimePicker?

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, why would you need this? I think you can just handle the `Changed` event and check whether the date is set to today.

Comment: What is platform where you work? Is it winforms, WPF, ASP.Net or something else?

Comment: Win7 and WinXP seems have different behavior when user click the "Go to today" button. On Win7, after click the button, the calender window did not close. While on WinXP, it automatically closed the calender window. So, I need to capture the click event when "Go to today" button is being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) event of [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) Control and check if the selected date is today's date. Like this -

```
    // ValueChanged Event
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hola !!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, how do I know is it actually the "Go to today" or just clicked at the current date on the calender?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using win xp and .net 3.5. you can use the mouse down event, it will be fired if you click in the control itself and on "today" but NOT if you click in the dropped down calender anywhere else than "today". to avoid the event is fired when i click on the control itself i use the return statement.
this event sets the actual time only if you click "today".
unfortunately in win8 the mousedown event is not fired...

```
    private void dateTimePicker2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = dateTimePicker2.Location;
        Point mouse_pt = dateTimePicker2.Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        int diff_x = mouse_pt.X - pt.X;
        int diff_y = mouse_pt.Y - pt.Y;
        if (diff_y < dateTimePicker2.Size.Height || diff_x > dateTimePicker2.Size.Width )
            return;
        DateTime tim_cal = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
        tim_cal = tim_cal.Date + ts;
        dateTimePicker2.Value = tim_cal;
    }
```